# Wordpress: link logo to the splashpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on this **Wordpress** [website](http://ergon.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/home/) and as you can see is a one scroll landing page.

What i need is to link the logo to this splash [page](http://ergon.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/)  because now, on click, is a simple anchor point (to top page).

How can i do it?

header.php code

```
<header><!-- Start of header -->
        <div class="full-width-container navcssmenu-cont">  
        <div class="center-header-container no-pad-lr nav-cssmenu" style="max-width: <?php echo $header_max_width . 'px'; ?>">
            <div id="cssmenu" class="cssmenu">
                <?php $home_url = ( is_page_template('template-onepage.php') || is_front_page() ) ? '#' : esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
                <?php $logo_onclick = ( is_page_template('template-onepage.php') || is_front_page() ) ? 'onclick="sierraHeaderLogoScroll()"' : '' ?>
                <div class="logo"><a class="logo-a" href="<?php echo $home_url ?>" <?php echo $logo_onclick ?>><?php sierra_opt_header_logo(); ?></a></div>
                <div id="head-mobile"></div>
                <div class="btn-menu"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="search-button-trigger search-btn-no-query"><i class="fa fa-search centered-icon"></i></a>
                        <?php my_custom_primary_menu(); ?> 
                    <a href="#" class="search-button-trigger search-btn-query"><i class="fa fa-search centered-icon"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <!-- Search pop-up -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'search', 'sierra' ); ?>
            <!-- end search pop-up -->


</header> <!-- Enf of header -->
```

Thanks in Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basic HTML question. Replace your code in template to:
    `<a href="/" class="logo-a">
        <img alt="Ergon-I" src="http://ergon.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ergonidee_LOGO-01.png">
    </a>`

Comment: Hi, i edited the post with the `header.php` code. Shoud i change something here i guess: `<div class="logo"><a class="logo-a" href="<?php echo $home_url ?>" <?php echo $logo_onclick ?>><?php sierra_opt_header_logo(); ?></a></div> <div class="logo"><a class="logo-a" href="<?php echo $home_url ?>" <?php echo $logo_onclick ?>><?php sierra_opt_header_logo(); ?></a></div>` right?

Comment: I made it. Thanks!